# DataTable Import Row last two column was null

Tags: c#, datatable

I have the code as below:

```
var saveData = new DataTable();
saveData = dataResult.clone();
foreach (DataRow row in dataResult.Rows)
{
   if (!row.isNull(0))
   {
       saveData.ImportRow(row);
   }
}
```

The dataResult table has 7 columns and 3 rows.

After `importrow` to the `saveData`. All the rows in `saveData` are the same with dataResult except the last 2 columns of last row in saveData was nulled

Why are the columns 5 & 6 in the last row of saveData null?

Below are 2 screenshots. I cannot upload directly to this website yet.
http://www.flickr.com/photos/105089878@N03/10218878706/

http://www.flickr.com/photos/105089878@N03/10218972883/in/photostream/

Comment: The links to the screenshots are broken. Please fix them.

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I've just reuploaded the screenshot.